# Table design for hierarchical data

Tags: sql, database-design, db2

i am trying to design a table which contains sections and each section contains tasks and each task contains sub tasks and so on. I would like to do it under one table. Please let me know the best single table approach which is scalable. I am pretty new to database design. Also please suggest if single table is not the best approach then what could be the best approach to do this. I am using db2.

Comment: You should take time to respond to any of the three (3) answers below which I believe has merits as solution to your problem. Not doing so would make you unattractive as far as getting decent response from SO community in the future. If the answer is close to your solution that your desire or it is close to the ideal then tell the poster. Or if not then you could at least point out which area should the one who answers your question should focus (and improve).

Answer (score 1):

Put quite simply, I would say use 1 table for tasks.

In addition to all its various other attributes, each task should have a primary identifier, and another column to optionally contain the identifier of its parent task.

If you are using DB2 for z/OS, then you will use a [recursive query with a common table expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_xmprecursivecte.htm).  Otherwise you you can use a [hierarchical recursive query in DB2 for i](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzhierquery.htm), or possibly [in DB2 for LUW](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0052877.html) (Linux, Unix, Windows).

Other designs requiring more tables, each specializing in a certain part of the task:subtask relationship, may needlessly introduce issues or limitations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

One idea is to use two tables: Sections and Tasks

There could be a one to many relationship between the two. The Task table could be designed as a tree with a TaskId and a ParentTaksId which means you can have Tasks that go n-levels deep (sub tasks of sub tasks og sub tasks etc). Every Task except for the root task will have a parent.

I guess you can also solve this by using a single table where you just add a section column to the Task table I described above.

Comment: Your last sentence is pretty good except that you don't have a section column but a object_type column. Sections, tasks, subtasks would be different object ids. You could also add more object classes later if you wish, like Story or Subsection. By putting everything in one table you get flexibility when it comes to how many hierarchy levels you can store. However, you loose the ability to use foreign keys to enforce the relationship between the different hierarchy levels, e.g. a task can never have a subtask as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put everything into one table although convenient will be inefficient in the long run. This would mean you will be storing unnecessary repeated groups of data in your database which would not be processor and memory friendly at all. It would in fact violate the [Normalization rules](http://holowczak.com/database-normalization/) and to be more specific the `1st Normal Form` which says that there should be no repeating groups that could be found in your table. And it would actually also violate the `3rd Normal Form` which means there will be no (transitional) dependency of a non-primary key to another non-primary key.

To give you an illustration, I will put your design into one table. Although I will be guessing on the possible fields but just bear with it because this is for the sake of discussion. Look at the graphics below:

[image]

If you look the graphics above (although this is rather small you could download the image and see it closer for yourself), the `SectionName`, `Taskname`, `TaskInitiato`r, `TaskStartDate` and `TaskEndDate` are unnecessary repeated which as I mentioned earlier a violation of the `1st Normal Form`.

Secondly, `Taskname`, `TaskInitiator`, `TaskStartDate` and `TaskEndDate` are functionally dependent on TaskID which is not a primary key instead of SectionID which in this case should be the primary key (if on a separate table). This is violation of 3rd Normal Form which says that there should be no Transitional Dependence or non-primary key should be dependent on
another non-primary key.

Although there are instances that you have to de-normalized but I believe this one should be normalized. In my own estimation there should be three tables involved in your design, namely, `Sections`,`Tasks` and `SubTasks` that would like the one below.

[image]

`Section` is related to `Tasks`, that is, a section could have many `Tasks`.
And `Task` is related to `Sub-Tasks`, that is, a `Task` could have many `Sub-tasks`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the original poster does not know, how many levels of hierarchy will be needed (hence "and so on"). His problem is to create a design that can hold a structure of any depth.

Imho that is a complex issue that does not have a single answer. When implementing such a design you need to count such factors as:

Will the structure be fairly constant? (How many writes?)
How often will this structure be read?
What operations will need to be possible? (Get all children objects of a given object? Get the parent object? Get the direct children?)

If the structure will be constant You could use the nested set model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

In this way the table has a 'left' and 'right' column. The parent object has its left and right column encompasing the values of any of its children object.

In that way you can list all the children of an object using a query like this:

```
SELECT child.id
FROM table AS parent
JOIN table AS child
    ON child.left BETWEEN parent.left AND parent.right
    AND child.right BETWEEN parent.left AND parent.right
WHERE
    parent.id = @searchId
```

This design can be VERY fast to read, but is also EXTREMELY costly when the structure changes (for example when adding a child to any object You will have to update any object with a 'right' value that is higher than the inserted one).

If you need to be able to make changes to structure in real time you should probably use a design with two tables - one holding the objects, the second the structure (something like parentId, childId, differenceInHierarchyLevels).